# unable to see WSDL in Salesforce

Tags: wsdl, salesforce

I have created a new salesforce trial account and wanted to integrate cast iron to the sales force.

now my question is like are there some sample wsdl provided by salesforce(partner,Enterprise) when we go the following--

Setup---Develop--API(as I am unable to see any WSDL there)

or we have to upload the wsdl(through some technique) and then from API we can download it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how you are trying to do the integration.

Do you want Salesforce to make callouts to the the Cast Iron web service API?

Or do you want Cast Iron to call into the Salesforce APIs?

For the former, you can create Apex classes for a SOAP WSDL using the Salesforce WSDL2Apex tool. You can then used those classes to callout to the web service as required. Remember to add the domain to the Remote Sites so the callout will be allowed. See [Apex Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#Apex_Callouts)

For the latter, you can use the WSDLs from Setup | Develop | API to allow an external tool to call into Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the WSDLs are not available in a trial org.  If you want to get an understanding of how the WSDLs work with CastIron, I would recommend signing up for a free developer account at https://developer.salesforce.com/.  It is a fully functional environment with user/data/access limitations: perfect for one or two users, can't be used in place of a licensed production org.

For more info on how to use the WSDLs once you get them, look here:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_partner.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_partner.htm|SkinName=webhelp